# need help in sql join to get output from three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have three tables like this:

**table module:**

```
+----------+-------------+
| Moduleid | Module name |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | m1          |
|        2 | m2          |
|        3 | m3          |
|        4 | m4          |
+----------+-------------+
```

**table: problem**

```
+-----------+----------+
| problemid | moduleid |
+-----------+----------+
| p1        | m1       |
| p2        | m1       |
| p3        | m2       |
| p4        | m2       |
| p5        | m3       |
| p6        | m3       |
| p7        | m4       |
| p8        | m4       |
+-----------+----------+
```

**table ticket:**

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| TicketID | problemid | moduleid |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|     1233 | p1        | m1       |
|     1234 | p3        | m2       |
|     1235 | p1        | m1       |
|     1236 | p4        | m2       |
|     1237 | p8        | m4       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

I want an output like this:

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| modulename | problemname | num of tickets |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
| m1         | p1          |              2 |
| m1         | p2          |              0 |
| m2         | p3          |              1 |
| m2         | p4          |              1 |
| m3         | p5          |              0 |
| m3         | p6          |              0 |
| m4         | p7          |              0 |
| m4         | p8          |              1 |
+------------+-------------+----------------+
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your purpose? Count tickets grouped by problem and module? If so you don't need to join tables, just use table `ticket`.

Comment: LEFT JOIN, GROUP BY with COUNT.

Comment: if i use table ticket i will get only the modules and problems for which ticket exist, but i want all the entries of modules and problems and if a ticket dont exist for the problem and module, 0 should come.

Comment: He needs a join since he needs 0's in his output if a ticket doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made up some column names here:

```
select m.Module_name, p.Problem_name, count(t.TicketID) as no_tickets
from modules m
  left join ticket t on m.Moduleid = t.Moduleid
  left join problem p on t.problemid = p.problemid
group by m.Module_name, p.Problem_name
```

`LEFT JOIN` is there to also return modules without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select p.moduleid as modulename,
p.problemid as problemname,
count(t.moduleid) as [no of tickets]
from problem p
left join ticket t
on p.problemid = t.problemid
group by p.moduleid,
p.problemid;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the bad table structure

change your table structure like

table module:

```
+----------+-------------+
|Moduleid(PK)| Module name |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | m1          |
|        2 | m2          |
|        3 | m3          |
|        4 | m4          |
+----------+-------------+
```

table: problem

```
+-----------+----------+
| problemid(PK) | moduleid(FK) |
+-----------+----------+
| p1        | 1       |
| p2        | 1       |
| p3        | 2       |
| p4        | 2       |
| p5        | 3       |
| p6        | 3       |
| p7        | 4       |
| p8        | 4       |
+-----------+----------+
```

table ticket:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| TicketID(PK) | problemid(FK) | moduleid(FK) |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|     1233 | p1        | 1       |
|     1234 | p3        | 2       |
|     1235 | p1        | 1       |
|     1236 | p4        | 2       |
|     1237 | p8        | 4       |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

> this structure'll help you in the future development or in the
>   modification of your application.

and you can try:

```
select m.ModuleName, p.ProblemName,count(TicketID ) from tbl_Module m
left join tbl_ticket t on m.ModuleId = t.ModuleId
  left join tbl_problem p on t.ProblemId = p.ProblemId
group by m.ModuleName, p.ProblemName
```